# How to show as empty the columns of a mySQL table that I don't want to have data in?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My structure is explained as follow:
I have 2 tables, `alerts_conditions` and `alerts_list`

The `id` is always found on `alerts_list` table.
So, if the `id` is found on `alerts_conditions` that means it has also a row in `alerts_list`.

But, in some cases, the id is **not** found on `alerts_conditions` so it is only found on `alerts_list`.

In this case, the output contains information that are irrelevant with the `id` (in fact it takes the columns of the first `alerts_conditions` row)

My question is how can I change my query so when the id is **only** found on `alerts_list`, the columns of the `alerts_conditions` to be null/empty ?

In my case below, 50 is found only on `alerts_list`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   alerts_conditions, 
       alerts_list 
WHERE  (alerts_conditions.alerts_conditions_alert = 50 OR alerts_list.alerts_id=50)
       AND alerts_conditions.company_id = 1 
LIMIT  1
```

**Please pay attention:**

IF the id exists in `alerts_list` that does not necessary mean that it exists on `alerts_conditions` too. But if the id is found on `alerts_conditions` exists, then it exists on `alerts_list` too.

Comment: Hint: You'll want to use an `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @TheDetective hi there, do you mean UNION?

Comment: @TheDetective any possible solution since the answers do not return the expected result?

Comment: You have not mentioned anything about `company_id = 1`, that is why your getting confusing answers.

Comment: @Sal fair enough, but the answers contain the `company_id=1` clause...

Comment: Since answers do not return the expected result you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use left join and then check both condition(NULL /empty)

```
SELECT al.* , ac.* 
FROM alerts_list al 
LEFT JOIN alerts_conditions ac 
on(al.alerts_d=ac.alerts_conditions_alert)
WHERE  
(
   alerts_conditions.alerts_conditions_alert = 50 
   OR 
   alerts_list.alerts_id=50
) AND 
alerts_conditions.company_id = 1 
AND 
(ac.alerts_conditions_alert IS NULL OR ac.alerts_conditions_alert= '')
```

Comment: have in mind that IF the id exists in `alerts_list` that does not necessary mean that it exists on `alerts_conditions` too. But if the id is found on `alerts_conditions` exists, then it exists on `alerts_list` too.

Comment: I just point out the id for both tables common column key in the join condition and an extra where conditiin

Comment: I am trying to fix this: `SELECT al.* , ac.* 
FROM alerts_list al 
LEFT JOIN alerts_conditions ac 
on(al.alerts_id=ac.alerts_conditions_alert)
WHERE  
(
   ac.alerts_conditions_alert = 50 
   OR 
   al.alerts_id=50
) AND 
ac.company_id = 1 
AND 
(ac.alerts_conditions_alert IS NULL OR ac.alerts_conditions_alert= '')`

Comment: But why do you join `on al.alerts_id=ac.alerts_conditions_alert` while there is a possibility of not finding any result?

Comment: Because you want the result such that alert condition table do not have id

Comment: So I checked the null or empty in where condition

Comment: ok but the query does not return any. please firstly update your code with the one I posted.

Comment: I think , you are checking alerts_id 50 only

Comment: Looks like id `50` it is just and example of matching values on both tables. OP has stated that wants to see the nulls in `alerts_conditions`so you have to omit the `ac.alerts_conditions_alert IS NULL`.

Comment: @Sal with real data, 50 exists only in alerts_list and not in alerts_conditions

Comment: Then above query will always return a single result

Comment: @vjytiwari sorry but your answer does not answers the question above

Comment: Then both tables common column types may be diffrent. Should be same type

Comment: I am 100% sure , it must be return exact result as above question required

Comment: @vjytiwari it is the same type.